AWS RDS Postgres returning only first record
I'm building a simple Orders API on AWS using Serverless Framework.
I've created function to create, update, and retrieve records.
The database is a Postgres one so I am using npm pg withing my lambdas to access the DB and do the above operations.
For some reason, despite the creation of records seems to indicate multiple records have been created, when I try to retrieve them I only get the first one.
this is my code to create records
const pool = require('./pgConnection')

console.log(pool)

const createTableText = `
BEGIN;

DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'order_status') THEN
        CREATE TYPE order_status AS ENUM ('created', 'received', 'dispatched');
    END IF;
END
$$;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  orderRef VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  address_line_1 VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  address_line_2 VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  address_line_3 VARCHAR(250),
  city VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  county VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  postcode VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  pdf_cover TEXT NOT NULL,
  pdf_content TEXT NOT NULL,
  book_config TEXT NOT NULL,
  current_status order_status
);
`;

async function createTable() {
    try {
        await pool.query(createTableText);
        console.log("Table created successfully.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error creating table:", err);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
}


module.exports = async (event) => {

    try {

    console.log('Creating Event', JSON.parse(event.body))

    await createTable()

    const {
        orderRef,
        name,
        email,
        address_line_1,
        address_line_2,
        address_line_3,
        city,
        county,
        postcode,
        pdf_cover,
        pdf_content,
        book_config
    } = JSON.parse(event.body);

    const query = 'INSERT INTO orders(orderRef, name, email, address_line_1, address_line_2, address_line_3, city, county, postcode, pdf_cover, pdf_content, book_config, current_status) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13) RETURNING *;';
    console.log(query)
    const values = [
        orderRef,
        name,
        email,
        address_line_1,
        address_line_2,
        address_line_3,
        city,
        county,
        postcode,
        pdf_cover,
        pdf_content,
        book_config,
        'created'];

      const res = await pool.query(query, values);
      const numrows = await pool.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM orders;");
      console.log("ROW INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY", numrows);
      //console.log(res.rows)
      return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]) };
    } catch (err) {
      return { statusCode: 500, body: err.message };
    }

}


and this is the code I use to retrieve them
const pool = require('./pgConnection')
const Cursor = require('pg-cursor')


module.exports = async (event) => {
    try {
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM orders WHERE current_status = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3 ';
        const orderStatus = event.queryStringParameters.order_status
        const limit = event.queryStringParameters.limit
        const offset = event.queryStringParameters.offset

        const values = [orderStatus, limit, offset]; // Use the orderStatus from the query string
        const client = await pool.connect()
        const cursor = await client.query(new Cursor(query, values));

        let rows = await cursor.read(100)

        ///res.json(orders.rows);
        return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(rows)};
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        //res.status(500).send('Server error');
        return { statusCode: 500, body: err.message};
      }

}

Does anybody have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks,
Salvo

can you share the payloadof API call ? event.queryStringParameters.limit == ?

I pass the parameters in the URL, like this: https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/retrieve-orders?order_status=dispatched&limit=10&offset=0
But I've also tried removing offset and limits and just returning all records with SELECT * FROM orders. Nothing, still returning only the first record
